# How to access local variable in local inner class has a field name like name of local variable

Tags: java

How to access local variable?

```
void do1() {

    final int i = 1; // (*)

    class A {
        int i = 2;
        void do2() {
            //how to access local variable i (*) ?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly add more Explanation to your question.

Comment: Simply put: You can't, because `i` is local. But you could add a constructor for `A` to hand `i` in at object creation.

Comment: @clcto 1) The code compiles "as it is" at my IDE (IntelliJ), 2) No, `i` and `this.i` refer to the `i` of `A` and not of the local variable `i` in `do1()`.

Comment: in class A, Is there any way to access to local variable i in DO1 method?

Comment: @ShenAu Yes, create a constructor taking in `i` and call it to create an object of `A`.

Comment: @Smutje: I want to access directly local variable from class A !

Comment: What problem is it that you are trying to solve here? http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

You can't as it is shadowed by the class variable. The easiest way to overcome it is to rename one of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here:

Pass in the outer `i` value to `A`.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().do1();
    }

    void do1() {

        final int i = 1; // (*)

        class A {
            A(int outerI) {
                this.outerI = outerI;
            }

            private int outerI;
            int i = 2;
            void do2() {
                System.out.println(outerI); // I want 1 here.
            }
        }

        new A(i).do2();
    }
}
```

Or use sane variable names:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().do1();
    }

    void do1() {

        final int i = 1; // (*)

        class A {
            int j = 2;
            void do2() {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

        new A().do2();
    }
}
```